# Getting name from hibernate for class

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

I have a project with supporting XML-config. Now we wanna add hibernate config for entities via annotation. Seems it possible and works (correct me if I am mistaken). The issue is that our system

```
private String entityName() {
    String name = null;
    try {
        String longName = getDaoFactory().getSessionFactory().getClassMetadata(entityClass).getEntityName();
        name = longName.substring(longName.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.error("Exception getting name from hibernate for class: " + entityClass);
        name = null;
    }
    return name;
}
```

This method works well for entities with xml-config, but how to get a name for an entity which is configurated by annotation?

Thank you in advance for any recommendation and suggestion :)

UPD:

from init session factory method:

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration(); 
configuration.addResource("resources/administrator/queries.hbm.xml");
StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration
        .getProperties());
SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());
setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
return configuration;
```

Comment: whats the hibernate version?

Comment: 1st. Checked by org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version.VERSION

Comment: via org.hibernate.Version.getVersionString() it shows me 4.3.5Final

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a session Factory like this.

```
public static SessionFactory buildSessionFactoryFromAnnotatedClasses(){
    StandardServiceRegistry standardRegistry =
        new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(// pass org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration object here)
            .getProperties()).build(); // Configuration object has properties

    MetadataSources sources = new MetadataSources(standardRegistry);
    sources.addAnnotatedClass(MyClass.class);// MyClass is your java annotated class
    Metadata metaData = sources.getMetadataBuilder().build();
    return metaData.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();
  }
```

Comment: @user3650408 it worked ? if not then what is the problem ?

Comment: this is close to real solution, very thank you. Any idea how to manage it without adding one-by-one entities? Would be greate to find gerenal way, do not felepnd on amount of annotated classes

Comment: @user3650408 pass a argument `List<Class> classes` in this method and add classes in the loop `classes.forEach(sources::addAnnotatedClass);` . you have to tell them before creating the sessionfactory.  I didn't see any method which add on run time.

Comment: I tried:configuration.addResource("resources/tax/queries-custom.hbm.xml");

  configuration.addAnnotatedClass(TicketNumber.class);


  configuration.setProperties(getHibernateSettings());
  StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration
    .getProperties());
//  configuration.configure();
  SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());
  setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
  return configuration;  It does not work :(

Comment: unfortunately, nope(

Comment: @user3650408 it works perfectly fine for me. Try to  add annotated classes via `MetadataSources` .

Comment: it works for loading by bean name, but not interface. I need to load by interface name. I added name in @Entity, but it still load metadata for a class by bean name, not interface(

Comment: @user3650408 can you provide more detail or add more code in Question? what interface in not loaded ? only beans are mapped to a table. you cannot mapped a interface to a table .